# Let vs Var with AsyncStorage Strange Exception

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-ios

To replicate the below, run this code on `React Native` `0.59.8`

I have a function that looks like the below:

```
import AsyncStorage from 'react-native';

const saveToStorage = async (value) => {
    await AsyncStorage.setItem('@store.key', value);
    let value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@store.key');
    // Exception is thrown on ios because value is seen as null
}
```

But if I changed let to var the request is processed successfully.

```
const saveToStorage = async (value) => {
    await AsyncStorage.setItem('@store.key', value);
    var value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@store.key');
    // No exception is thrown on ios
}
```

Does anyone have an idea what is going on?

Comment: Change the variable name to something other than `value`

Answer (score 0):

I would comment this if I could but I think there's a couple things that you could change. Don't name that variable value because you are passing a parameter called value into your async function, so value will already be defined. Also I think you are missing an `await` in your `AsyncStorage.getItem('@store.key')`